# Can you get a multiple uncontrolled Autocomplete's value in a route's action function?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I use the latest React Router and Material UI to implement a form that creates a post.

My form asks for some data e.g. a title, a body and some tags.

My action reads the values from the request's formData unless it's a multiple `Autocomplete`.

```
import { Form } from 'react-router-dom';

export async function action({ request }) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const newPost = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  
  // newPost.tags is an empty string
}

export default function NewPost() {
  return (
    <Form method="post">
      <TextField name="title" />
  
      <TextField name="body" />
  
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        options={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} name="tags" />
        )}
      />

      <Button type="submit">Create post</Button>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Comment: The only way I can think of is making the Autocomplete controlled and send a hidden input with the selected tags as a comma separated string.

Comment: That seems logical.